# "Recluse Stays Home" hacking quest unbeatable

Tags: pc, nier-automata

In Pascal's Village, the "Recluse Stays Home" side quest asks the player to play hacking. However for some PC players this seems impossible as time is always short by one second even for the perfect play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be a problem for PC player who uses the FAR mod to limit the framerate. The player's bullet shooting speed is affected by the framerate. If the framerate is below 50 FPS, the shoot speed will be too slow to break all the blocks.